# Does this integral have any closed form? $\int\frac{1}{x+\sin(x+1)}\mathop{\mathrm dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

Does this integral have any closed form? $$\int\frac{1}{x+\sin(x+1)}\mathop{\mathrm dx}$$

I think the substitution $x=(u-1)+2\pi$ will do it, no?

Comment: Apparently, no.

Comment: Your substitution will turn it into a rational function in $x$ and $\sin(x)$, but I don't think that such a thing is guaranteed to have an elementary closed form.

Comment: Not according to Mathematica & Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this integral have any closed form?

No. At least not according to [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: Can you provide details?  Assuming the material on those two pages, what are the steps to apply them to this particular integral?

Comment: I hope you didn't honestly think that the entire algorithm fits into two pages. :-) The links were simply provided so as to help familiarize the reader with some basic concepts, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

By using the formula

[image]

We have $$\int\dfrac{1}{x+\sin(x+1)}dx=x\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^{2^n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{m+1}}{mx+2^n\sin\dfrac{mx+2^n}{2^n}}+C$$

Comment: I edited the post so the image would show directly, hope you don't mind.